# JSON-B deserializing date string into joda DateTime without altering model classes

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, jsonb

I am working on deserializing a JSON date field into an external model class. The request looks like:

```
{
  "name": "Bob",
  "lastName":"Bobertson",
  "date": "2019-03-12"
}
```

Here is the code I am using to deserialize. Note the class called in question is external but matches the incoming request.

```
import javax.json.bind.Jsonb;

private static Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();

public static External deserExternal(String jsonRQ) {
    return jsonb.fromJson(jsonRQ, External.class);
}
```

Calling this method like below results in

> javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Error deserialize JSON value into type: class org.joda.time.LocalDate

```
String jsonRQ= readFile("./path/to/file.json");
External externalRQ = deserExternal(jsonRQ);
```

All solutions I have found so far involve annotating the models to account for joda types but I do not have that option. How can I accomplish this by editing the deserializer only, preferably by allowing it to automatically convert date strings into joda DateTime as needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it via JACKSON you can use something like

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
mapper.readValue(jsonRQ, External.class);
```

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Not sure if you can switch libraries though

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Jackson seems to work for my case. Wonder if there is a JAX JSON-B solution as well